# Xamarin C# - Named argument specifications must appear after all fixed arguments

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am creating an application using Xamarin forms, and have imported the SKCanvas nuget package to allow drawing capability. On their documentation [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/drawing/introduction/) it is specified that the below code is how you obtain a canvas.

```
using (var surface = SKSurface.Create(width: 640, height: 480, SKImageInfo.PlatformColorType, SKAlphaType.Premul))
        {
            SKCanvas myCanvas = surface.Canvas;
        }
```

I am getting an error when I write this code, `Named argument specifications must appear after all fixed arguments have been specified`

I have seen a couple of questions similar to mine on here, but none of them apply directly to my problem

Comment: try putting "new" before last 2 value, This should fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you for replying. The error I am getting is for the `SKImageInfo.PlatformColorType`, I added a `new` before it but that made no difference

Comment: The error message seems painfully clear to me. What are you having trouble understanding? As the message says, all of the named argument specifications have to appear after all of the fixed-position arguments are specified. In practice, since you are trying to name the first two arguments, you'll have to either not do that, or name _all_ the arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

Either put the name to all the parameters:

```
using (var surface = SKSurface.Create (width: 640, height: 480, colorType: SKImageInfo.PlatformColorType, alphaType: SKAlphaType.Premul)) {
    SKCanvas myCanvas = surface.Canvas;

    // Your drawing code goes here.
}
```

Or remove the name from the first two (width and height):

```
using (var surface = SKSurface.Create (640, 480, SKImageInfo.PlatformColorType, SKAlphaType.Premul)) {
    SKCanvas myCanvas = surface.Canvas;

    // Your drawing code goes here.
}
```

Hope this helps.-

Comment: Thank you @apineda this was really helpful, I hadn't had this problem before and your example code made it easy to understand